# How to concatenate month number into table name

Tags: sql-server-2000

I like to concatenate the month number with a text to build table names. For example, I am trying to retreive data for May 2013, I would like to select from webproxylog5.

The following script

```
    select *
from webproxylog + '' + cast(month(dateadd(m,-2,getdate())) as varchar(2)) + ''
```

will result in the following error messsage:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Line 4: Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

What is wrong with this syntax?

Thank you,

Seyed

Answer (score 0):

you would need to build dynamic sql for that, 
something like

```
declare @sql varchar(200) 
set @sql= 'select * from webproxylog + ' + cast(month(dateadd(m,-2,getdate())) as varchar(2)) 
exec(@sql)
```